# How to draw squares in java and put values inside it?

Tags: java, linked-list, drawing

I have a Java program that has a linked list. I want to draw squares in command line and put the values of the linked list inside it. The output should be like this:

```
-----------------
| 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
-----------------
```

The numbers are just examples to show. This is what i have done so far:

```
public void display()
    {
        Node<data> temp = ll.getHead();//ll is linked list
        for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++)System.out.print("---------");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++)System.out.print("|       |");
        System.out.println();
        for(;temp!=null;temp = temp.next)System.out.print("|   "+temp.data.Value+"  |");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<ll.size();i++)System.out.print("|       |");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;ll.size();i++)System.out.print("---------");
        System.out.println();
 }
```

There is two problems with this code: it is not efficient at all, and if the value is more than 9 the lines will shift and all the drawing will be missed up. Is there a better way to do what i want? I assume this code is clear and enough to show the problem. If not please tell me to make it better. 
Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use the `format` method of the `String` class.  Have a look at the Javadoc for that method, and also the Javadoc for the `Formatter` class.  It should then be clear what you have to do.

Comment: *if the value is more than 9 the lines will shift and all the drawing will be missed up* that *problem* happens in a console. Copy the text into a decent text editor and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I would also look into using brackets more. There should be brackets around your for loop for easier readability (and it's an Oracle Java code convention)

Comment: @Ascalonian I would but unfortunately i was strongly asked to make it like this.

Comment: @hzjw Asked by whom?  If your professor is encouraging you to write code that looks like this, then he/she should not be teaching Java programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a StringBulder for the upper and lower lines because they are the same.
and you can build all the lines in the same loop, so that can handle variable lengths for values:

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

for(;temp!=null;temp = temp.next) {

  String value =Integer.toString(temp.data.Value);

  line.append("-");
  values.append("|");

  for(int i=0; i<value.length(); i++) { line.append("-"); }
  values.append(value);
}

line.append("-");
values.append("|");

System.out.println(line.toString());
System.out.println(values.toString());
System.out.println(line.toString());
```

Comment: In `temp.data.Value.toString();` did you mean to convert the int to string? if so, i think you need to do it like this: `String value =Integer.toString(temp.data.Value);` . please edit the answer so i can accept it. Thank you very very much.:)

Comment: sorry, I didn't know the type of temp.data.Value, I edit this.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the number  of dashes above and below n numbers is equal to 4n + 1. So, as for the loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (4 * ll.size()) + 1; i++) System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println();

// same as yours
for(;temp!=null;temp = temp.next)System.out.print("|   "+temp.data.Value+"  |");
    System.out.println();

for(int i = 0; i < (4 * ll.size()) + 1; i++) System.out.print("-");
```

Hope this will do the trick

EDIT: if your data are not numbers, then you will need to have a consistent space filled by each data. Then you will count the number of dashes for each square and get the formula for it.
Good luck